# iptables: only allow UDP packets that contain a specific string

Tags: iptables

How do I configure iptables so that only `UDP` packets that contain a specific string are allowed as an `INPUT`?

For example, I would like only `UDP` packets that contain the string `version` to be allowed.

Comment: normally, you go read `man iptables` then you say "whoa!" and do the things

Answer (score 0):

You can use a iptables extension for doing this.

Here is a link where you can read about string matching with iptables 
[from the web](https://blog.nintechnet.com/how-to-block-w00tw00t-at-isc-sans-dfind-and-other-web-vulnerability-scanners/)

You can of course doing what you expect with this technique. 
Good reading !